# Gaussian Basis function returns vector not scalar

Tags: matlab, vector, gaussian

I'm trying to implement the Gaussian basis function in matlab but I don't see how I can get it to NOT return a vector.  My data is 10,000 (samples) x 21 (features).  I've been doing research and I've seen suggestions to use the stats toolbox but I want to use just matlab code.  Below is the Gaussian basis function I am using.

[image]

Below is the matlab code that I am using.

```
function [ scalar_value ] = gaussian_basis( x_vector, mu_vector)
    % x_vector 1 x 21 vector
    % mu_vector 1 x 21 vector

    scalar_value = exp(-((x_vector - mu_vector).^2/ 2 * .5^2));
```

I don't know what I am missing.  As I mentioned I don't see how I can make this return a scalar value.  Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am lacking theory right now, but how is it supposed to return a scalar if you are giving vectors? The operation `(x_vector - mu_vector)` are componen-wise, so you will receive 21 scalar_values.

Comment: yeah that's where I am having problems.  From the resource I'm looking at it says, "Each basis function φj(x), j = 0,..M − 1 converts input vector x into a scalar value." thanks.

Comment: for any given x **value** you'll get a scalar. For a set of value, i.e. if x is a vector, you'll get a vector...

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or you are specifying the wrong basis function. I don't see how that basis function can give you a scalar given a vector input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that a Gaussian basis function is usually defined on

[image]

instead of on

[image]

If this is the correct interpretation, then you want:

```
scalar_value = exp(-sum((x_vector - mu_vector).^2, 2)/ (2 * .5^2));
```

instead of

```
scalar_value = exp(-((x_vector - mu_vector).^2/ 2 * .5^2));
```

The latter, as has been noted in the comments, will always return a vector, because you are not including any operations that aggregate over the second dimension.